# Cookies and authentication

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, cookies

I have the following point that I created with a C# API, this method if you send it a password and a user and everything is correct, it returns two cookies.
token and refreshToken

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Authenticate")]
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(IpLimitActions))]
        [EnableRateLimiting("General")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Autenticar([FromBody] AuthorizationRequest authorization)
        {
            try
            {
                var resultAuthorization = await _authorizationService.ReturnToken(authorization);
                if (resultAuthorization == null)
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Crear y configurar la cookie de token
                    var tokenCookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Secure = true, // Se debe configurar como true si el sitio es HTTPS
                        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, // O ajusta según los requisitos de seguridad
                        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30) // Tiempo de expiración de la cookie
                    };
                    Response.Cookies.Append("token", resultAuthorization.Token, tokenCookieOptions);
                    // Crear y configurar la cookie de refresh token
                    var refreshTokenCookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Secure = true, // Se debe configurar como true si el sitio es HTTPS
                        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, // O ajusta según los requisitos de seguridad
                        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24 * 7) // Tiempo de expiración de la cookie                     
                    };
                    Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", resultAuthorization.RefreshToken, refreshTokenCookieOptions);
                    return Ok();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Manejar otras excepciones no controladas
                throw new MethodsExceptions(StatusCod.UnprocessableContent, ex.Message, ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Since I react with typescript, I call this endpoint like this

```
export const login = (credentials: authInput) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  try {
    debugger
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/Authenticate`, credentials, { withCredentials: true });
    dispatch(setCredentials({}));
     const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
     console.log(cookies)
  } catch (error) {
    //Aquí podrías despachar otra acción para manejar el error
  }
};
```

Cookies are automatically set in the browser. This works correctly.

I have redux implemented

My question is this: if the token and refreshToken are set in the browser as cookies with the security HttpOnly = true, they are inaccessible from javascript.
How do I make the next requests that are made send this token that is in the cookie automatically in the following requests?
If this is done like this or I need to send the token another way and not as cookies, how does this token authentication work? or what is the correct way to do it

Comment: The browser cookies are set in the user temp space and are accessible by any app and any browser.

Comment: @jdweng But they arrive and configure themselves automatically. What I want is to be able to take that token and send it in future requests. When investigating they say that with this code withCredentials: true it will be taken automatically but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It depend on the expiration time of the cookie.  The cookie may only be valid for a short period of time.